# Unable to print output to the console in dojo

Tags: dojo

I'm a beginner in dojo, and I'm trying to print the output to console using dojo code. But I don't what's the problem in the following code, and how can I print the output to the console?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config = "async: true, isDebug : true" >
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id = "greeting">Hello</h1>
<script>
define(["dojo/dom"],function(dom) {
var Twitter = declare(null, {username:"defaultusername",
    say :function(msg)
    {
        console.log("Hello "+msg);
    }
});
var myInstance = new Twitter();
myInstance.say("Dojo");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using firefox, but I can't print output even in chrome.

Comment: consider this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/AgvFs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `require` instead of `define`:

```
<script>
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/declare"], function(dom, declare) {

    var Twitter = declare(null, {

        username: "defaultusername",

        say :function(msg) {
            console.log("Hello "+msg);
        }
    });

    var myInstance = new Twitter();
    myInstance.say("Dojo");
});
</script>
```

`Console` works, but your code inside callback function in `declare` is not being executed until you `require` it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `define` in inline script code, that is meant to be a class define, put in the topmost line of a class-file, meaning define maps the filename to the returned value of its function.

This means, if you have

```
dojo_toolkit /
  dojo/
  dijit/
  dojox/
  libs/
    myWidgets/
       foo.js
```

And foo.js reads

```
define(["dijit._Widget"], function(adijit) {
  return declare("libs.myWidgets.foo", [adijit], function() {
    say: function(msg) { console.log(msg); }
  });
});
```

Then a new module is registered, called `libs` / `myWidgets` / `foo`. You should make sure that the returned declare's declaredClass inside each define matches the file hierachy.

That being said, reason why define does not work for you is the explaination above. It is inline and has no `src` to guess the declaredClass name from. Rewrite your code to **define("aTwitterLogger", ["**:

```
define("aTwitterLogger", ["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom"],function(declare, dom) {
  var Twitter = declare(null, {
      username:"defaultusername",
      say :function(msg)
      {
          console.log("Hello "+msg);
      }
  });
  var myInstance = new Twitter();
  myInstance.say("Dojo");
});
```